# Anchor build error: cannot find version of aho-corasick dependency

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, cargo, build-bpf

I am having trouble building my Anchor project. I first got the error message "cargo pbf require libssl1.0.0". I installed the dependency libssl1.0.0 with the command sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main sudo apt update sudo apt install libssl1.0.0. However, I am still getting the error message "error anchor build".

Here is the output of the cargo build command:

BPF SDK: /root/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.13.6/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `aho-corasick = "^1.0.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.7.20, 0.7.19, 0.7.18, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `programs v0.1.0`

My project's Cargo.toml file is as follows:

[package]
name = "programs"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "programs"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
regex = "1.5.4"

I am using Anchor CLI version 0.27.0 and Solana CLI version 1.13.6.

I would appreciate any help you can provide in resolving this issue.

Thank you!